# MATLAB polyfit function not working

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

For some reason the polyfit function keeps giving me NaN for my function which I dont understand at all because when using another function, it works just fine. Here is my code:

```
lb=0; %lowerbound of data 
ub=10; %upperbound of data 
step=.001; %step-size through data 
a=.03; 
la=1482/120000; %1482 is speed of sound in water and 120kHz
ep1=.1;
ep2=.2;
x=lb:step:ub;
r_sq_des=0.99; %desired value of r^2 for the fit of data without noise 
 %present 
%  G = abs(sin((a/la)*pi.*x.*(sqrt(1+(1./x).^2)-1)));
%  r=x;

i=1; 

for x=lb:step:ub 
 G(i,1)= abs(sin((a/la)*pi*x*(sqrt(1+(1/x)^2)-1)));
%  N(i,1)=2*rand()-1; 
%  Ghat(i,1)=(1+ep1*N(i,1))*G(i,1)+ep2*N(i,1); 
 r(i,1)=x; 
 i=i+1; 
end

 Q=polyfit(r,G,2); %Polynomial fit of the data G(r) w.o. noise 
 Z=polyval(Q,r); %Evaluation of the polynomial fit for the data w.o.noise
```

Please advise.

Comment: G(1) is nan, that causes the problem.

Comment: @Daniel hey Daniel quick question because it is happening again when I add noise so the new equation is the Ghat equation that was commented out in the above. Also my new lower bound is .001. Any advice?

Comment: It's not that polyfit isn't working, you are dividing by zero on line `G(i,1)= abs(sin((a/la)*pi*x*(sqrt(1+(1/x)^2)-1)));`